# unexpected mysql -uroot authentication

Tags: mysql

So, unix root user can connect to mysql root user without password:

```
root@server $ mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 27
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

But unix user redmine can't:

```
root@server $ sudo -u redmine mysql -uroot
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I guess that mysqld is checking uid=1 over the connecting unix domain socket but I can't see where this is explained in the mysql docs. (strace shows the mysql shell process opening the unix domain socket successfully and closing it after getting a reply from the server)

How do I connect to the database root user without password as a non-root unix user ? (please, spare me the "it's not a good idea" line)

Comment: FYI, it appears there is no way to keep the root user without a password and connect to it with a non-root unix user.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the root user has a `/root/.my.cnf` file which contains the login credentials? You can configure `~redmine/.my.cnf` to contain your credentials:

```
[client]
password="yourpassword"
```

For more, see the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).